# prototype - simulate click on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How do i simulate a click on an anchor  (`<a>`) tag in prototype?

for example i would expect the below code to work in that clicking the 2nd link ("click me") would cause the `alert('here');` to be executed.

```
<a id="myLink" href="" onclick="alert('here'); return false;">don't click me</a>
<br />
<a href="" onclick="$('myLink').click(); return false;">click me</a>
```

thanks, p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `simulate()` method from the [Protolicious](http://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/master/event.simulate.js) library:

You can see the test sandbox [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RZEXv/), but with events added:

```
<a id="myLink" href="#">don't click me</a>
<br />
<a id="clicked" href="#">click me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe($('myLink'), 'click', function () { alert ('aaa'); return false; });
Event.observe($('clicked'), 'click', function () { alert ('bbb'); $('myLink').simulate('click'); return false; });
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried to run the code? because i think the problem might be that $('myLink') is not returning the HTMLElement object. It doesn't for me anyway...

Comment: Check out the revised answer with an example page :)

Comment: ah i see .. i need protolicious ... but surely there's a way in prototype without a 3rd party lib? thanks for the info .. at least i know there's a way. will hold out a little in case someone else has a prototype only answer.

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't require on a plugin??

Comment: Yes, me too I need a solution without a plug-in, just plain prototypejs

Comment: @Bogdan Constantinescu: This works, but only on newer browsers like the current release of Firefox or Google Chrome. With IE6 or IE7 it breaks. IE says that the element does not support the method. I don't think it is my fault, because on other browsers it works fine

Comment: this work very well ! 
you can just copy the linked script inside you js

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but try this:

```
<a id="myLink" href="" onclick="alert('here'); return false;">don't click me</a>
<br />
<a href="" onclick="Event.fire($('myLink'), 'click');">click me</a>
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot that Prototype Events are limited to custom events. Can I ask why you cant to simulate a click event? Chances are there's a better way to approach it.

Comment: because this other link has had a bunch of event listeners registered to it by a third party program. it would be easier to use the other link as a registry of sorts rather than plumb together all the event handlers on the link that actually gets clicked.